# prestashop logo url malfunctioning. How to resolve?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, mod-pagespeed

Installed bitnami prestashop in GCE, **friendly url** is working fine, only the LOGO showing in some times, giving Forbidden error most of the times. 
Whenever the logo appears,the url is correctly mapped to img/prestashop-logo-1514296542.jpg , whenever its not showing its mapped to img/xprestashop-logo-1514296542.jpg.pagespeed.ic.AN7WOFIVVf.webp and getting `403 Forbidden error`
with `You don't have permission to access /img/xprestashop-logo-1514296542.jpg.pagespeed.ic.AN7WOFIVVf.webp on this server.`

What is wrong with my prestashop? any idea where to lookinto?

The server is at http://35.227.153.253/

Answer (score 1):

The issue is at, pagespeed module in apache. Once disabled its all ok.

To disable PageSpeed, follow these steps:

Comment out the following lines in the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf file:

> Include conf/pagespeed.conf
>   Include conf/pagespeed_libraries.conf

Restart Apache:

> sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission problem (you cannot write this folder).

You should change folder (and subfolders) permissions to 777, you can do that with Filezilla if it's a distant server and you are on Windows or use linux terminal when in your Prestashop root folder :

```
 chmod 777 -R ./img/
```

Comment: Did, but not solved the issue. Its just showing the data available in the img folder. some times showing (first time) when refreh its not. Due to cache or something like ..

Answer (score 0):

**You don't have to disable the PageSpeed Module**, it should be last option. ;)

If you are sure about the **img/** permission (you can set as above message), you can try the flush cache.

- **#** sudo touch /opt/bitnami/apache2/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/cache.flush
- **#** sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache

Then, re-check your site if it countiunes, you can clear PS cache, it will be okay.

Good works!